# I want to validate if an email being submitting already exist in a text file (php)

Tags: php

Code is not working, please let me know what is being done wrong. I want to get the email being submitted by customer by form, and validate if it already exists in a particular file.

```
$email = isset($_POST["email"]) ? $_POST["email"] : ""; 
$file = fopen("emails.txt", "r");
$num = 0;
$text[] = 0;

//get lines in file
while (!feof($file)) {
    $text[$num] = fgets($file);
    $num= $num + 1;

    // validate if entry already exist
     if ($email == $text[$num]) {
             echo $email, $text[$num], ",";
    }
}

fclose($file);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) to check the email in string

```
//validate if entry already exist
if (strpos($text[$num], $email) !== false) {

     echo $email, $text[$num], ",";

}
```